# hadoop wordcount and upload file into hdfs

Tags: hadoop

hello everyone i am very new in hadoop and i install hadoop in pseudo mode.
configurations files are here

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name </name>
      <value> hdfs://localhost:9000 </value> 
   </property>

</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop_usr/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode </value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>file:///home/hadoop_usr/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode </value> 
   </property>

</configuration>
```

and am successfully start **datanode** and **namenode**

> Now i want to put my file into hdfs by using following way

[image: adding file into hdfs]
what's going wrong why i get error message. Please help me to resolve this problem

> If i using following way to put file into hdfs that time command is working fine. now i appand hdfs url.
>   [image: update file with hdfs url]
>   Please help me why i getting error in first way.
>   Because when in running my wordcount.jar that time am also getting error message when i mentioned data.txt as input file on which operation sould be performed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first put operation to `data/data.txt` is not working is likely that you do not have a folder `data` in your hdfs yet.
You can just create it using `hadoop fs -mkdir /data`.

Comment: thanks @Armin Braun. then  >  **hadoop fs -ls**
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop_usr supergroup          0 2016-12-22 23:17 data
                                                                                                                            then i use >  **hadoop jar wordcount.jar hdp.WordCount data/data.txt wordcountoutput**
   and get  **org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop_usr/data/data.txt already exists**

Comment: please help me out so at least i am able to run my first hadoop program

Comment: @sawaisingh what Wordcount job are you running?, it seems it wants to use the first argument  as the output directory?

Comment: really thanks man. I was stuck from last two days. Its my mistake really thanks man.  Thanks alot

Comment: @sawaisingh no problem :)